# Thymeleaf doesn't select disabled option

Tags: thymeleaf, materialize

I am using **Materializecss** select form http://materializecss.com/forms.html#select and it requires for correct behavior first option to be disabled and selected. **Thymeleaf** ignores disabled option despite it is selected. Instead it selects first non-disabled option.

```html
<div class="input-field col s6">
    <select th:field="*{locale}" th:errorclass="invalid">
        <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choose your option</option>
        <option value="cs">Czech</option>
        <option value="en">English</option>
    </select>
    <label>Locale</label>
</div>
```

Czech is automatically selected, but I want to see **Choose your option** to be selected instead.

Comment: Try to use `th:selected` and `th:disabled` instead. And if you try, replace `th:field` with `name` attribute according to [this](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/th-selected-not-working-on-multiple-select-td4025883.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on Enigo comment, I have made it working by replacing `th:field` in select element with `name` and `id`. I have also added `th:disabled` and `th:selected` to the first option for it to be disabled and selected by default.

```html
<select name="locale" id="locale" th:errorclass="invalid" required="required">
    <option value="" th:disabled="disabled" th:selected="selected">
        Choose your option
    </option>
    <option value="cs">Czech</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

**th:field** and **th:selected** dont work at the same time.
For this remove th:field and replace them for **id** and **name** attributes manualy.

Check the forum [thymeleaf-forum](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/th-selected-not-working-on-multiple-select-td4025883.html)

I have the same problem.

I share my code.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select id="doc" name="doc" th:with="doc=*{doc}">
                    <option value="" th:disabled="disabled" selected="true"
                       th:text="${status==true}? 'Seleccione tipo de documento' : ${doc}">Seleccione
                       tipo de documento</option>
                    <option th:each="tipoDoc : ${tipoDocs}" th:text="${tipoDoc}"
                       th:value="${tipoDoc}" />
              </select>
    <label>Documento</label>
</div>
```

Salu2